# Cross-country style baskets for Black Diamond collapsible poles

Tags: gear, cross-country-skiing, trekking-poles

I have two pairs of collapsible poles made by Black Diamond (Traverse and Expedition 3). I tried using them for cross-country skiing on groomed trails, but the baskets I was using (the trekking and compactor powder versions, see images below) weren't ideal, as the forwarding facing part of the basket would get caught in the compacted snow and be hard to pull out. The baskets of cross-country poles are commonly one-sided to avoid this issue.

Black Diamond unfortunately doesn't offer other baskets; their suggestion was to cut off some material from my baskets to fix the problem.

Perhaps there is another solution? Other manufacturers like Exel, Komperdell, Leki, Swix and Yoko sell replacement tips with proper cross-country baskets, but I'm not sure if they fit the Black Diamond poles.

BD trekking baskets:

[image: trekking basets]

BD compactor powder baskets:

[image]

---

Update: I found that both the large and small versions of the [Leki Contour baskets](https://www.leki.com/skitour-schneeschuh/accessoires/2466/contour-basket/) both fit fine onto my BD poles and have the basic shape that I was looking for. But they still occasionally catch in packed snow on groomed trails (they are after all made for ski touring). There may be another option to cutting off material (which I'm hesitant to do): removing the tips and installing cross-country style tips (which usually have cross-country style baskets attached to them). However here I would still need to know which tips from other companies would fit the BD poles.

Comment: It seems that "cut off some material" is the answer.

Comment: @MartinF Actually I ordered Leki Contour Baskets and they fit (https://www.leki.com/skitour-schneeschuh/accessoires/2466/contour-basket/). I will try them out this weekend and post more details.

Comment: Can you buy an another set of the existing tips that you don't want to cut, and cut into those? That alleviates the risk you feel you have. Also Unanswered questions dont help the site, If you have come up with your own solution even though it is less than perfect, its good to submit that as an answer to your own question. That way people will be able to reference it and see that there was even a partial solution rather than just another unanswered question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Leki Contour-Basket small (75 mm) fit the poles and have worked quite well for me so far: [image]